# I forked github repository and modified some sources. "pip install git+http://..." installs everything except a few folders

Tags: python, git, pip

I forked a repository, modified some files, added new folders `static/slideshows/css` with a file `slideshows.css`.

When I do "pip install git+https://github.com/TitanFighter/emencia-django-slideshows.git", `pip` installs everything (including modified files), but except `static/slideshows/css/slideshows.css`.

When I do `git clone`, everything is ok.

`setup.py` is forked and not modified:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='emencia-django-slideshows',
    version=__import__('slideshows').__version__,
    description=__import__('slideshows').__doc__,
    long_description=open('README.rst').read(),
    author='David Thenon',
    author_email='dthenon@emencia.com',
    url='http://pypi.python.org/pypi/emencia-django-slideshows',
    license='MIT',
    packages=find_packages(),
    classifiers=[
        'Programming Language :: Python',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
        'Operating System :: OS Independent',
        'Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable',
        'Environment :: Web Environment',
        'Framework :: Django',
        'Framework :: Django :: 1.7',
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'Topic :: Internet :: WWW/HTTP',
        'Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Python Modules',
    ],
    install_requires=['Django>=1.7'],
    include_package_data=True,
    zip_safe=False
)
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Please add the `setup.py` to your question!

Comment: @KlausD. Added. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was necessary to add `recursive-include slideshows/static *` to `MANIFEST.in` file.